# Nested property or temp variable for iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If i have object lets say with 3 level nesting with 100 props each and have some iteration function that use one of object value on last level 20 times.

Is it better to make temporary variable for iteration, or accessing property 20 times is almost the same for efficiency?

```
let obj = {a:{b:{c:'nested on level 3 property #89'}}}
//or is better
let temp = obj.a.b.c

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
  //what is better to use, obj.a.b.c or temp 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "temporary value" ? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @PaulCosma sorry, i mean variable

Comment: Depends on the use case. Property retrieval is unlikely to be a performance problem unless you have getters in there. But honestly, with performance, the best way to find out is to test it yourself and see.

Comment: i am to lazy: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties

Comment: Don't worry about this unless it's actually causing a performance problem. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Most of the time the difference is negligible. Write it in the way that's most clear to the reader, worry about performance later if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use it like your example and create it globally the `var` will be created as an object and therefore will not have benefits as to access your object property.

If the example would be inside a function variables declared by `var` will be treated differently and be faster than accessing an object property but we are talking about nanoseconds differences...

To worry about that is probably too much worries...